# Database inserting image instead if text

Tags: javascript, sql

I'm using this bit of code to insert and select text from a database. How can I implement this for images instead of text. I've done my far share of google(ing) I couldn't find anything to help.

```
var index_count = 0
var up_check = 0

function get_db(a, up_check) {
var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("DB5", "1.0", "The Example QML SQL!", 1000000);
db.transaction(
    function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Greeting(salutation TEXT, salutee TEXT)');
        for ( var z=0; z<1000; z++){
           tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Greeting VALUES(?, ?)', [ 'Movie', z ]);
        }

       var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Greeting');
       var r = ""

            for(var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                 if (i>index_count-1 && up_check ===0)
                    r += rs.rows.item(i).salutation + ": " + rs.rows.item(i).salutee + "\t\t"

                 if (up_check === 1){
                     var size_check =0
                     if (i >index_count-11   && size_check !==9)  {
                       r += rs.rows.item(i).salutation + ": " + rs.rows.item(i).salutee + "\t\t"
                      size_check++
                     }
                  }
              }

       console.log(r);
       index_count=a;
        return r;
    })}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass path to the image file as a value to a filed, that can store images. Your table example:

```
create table testblob (
    image_id        tinyint(3)  not null default '0',
    image           blob        not null
);
```

DB command would be:

```
INSERT INTO testblob (ID,IMAGE) VALUES(1,LOAD_FILE('D:/test.txt'));
```

Javascript:

```
ImagePath_from_MyForm = 'C:\temp\test.jpg'
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Greeting VALUES(?, ?)', [ z, ImagePath_from_MyForm ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm lost on how to do that